# VS2012: 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-sdk

I tried VS2012 Native Tools, Cross Tools and Developers command prompt.
And it does not recognize 'nmake'.
It didn't work on VS2010 either.

On VS2008, it could not find depencies like windows.h

I want to build a static library curl for VS2012:
http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/

Comment: So, check PATH and see if it contains the dir that contains nmake.exe.

Answer (score 18):

for visual studio 2015 community edition add the following path to your system environment path

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

in the above path there is the nmake command

Comment: This worked for VS 2017 Enterprise Edition. Variable name: nmake. Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

Answer (score 12):

find the following dir, and run `vsvars32.bat`

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools
```

inside your DOS window, then try to run `nmake`

You can also click `start` -> `All programs` -> `Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0` -> `Visual studio tools` -> `VS2012 x86 native tools command` .

Comment: VS2012 is version 11.0
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

Comment: After running vsvars32.bat: ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder