# c++ HTTP request without .dll files at runtime

Tags: c++

Libraries like curl require you to have .dll files when running .exe

In theory you should be able to link those .dll statically to the .exe

But I can't find a way to do that without errors and crashes.

But are there libraries which don't require external .dll files at runtime?
That allow me to do a HTTP request?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411259/using-libcurl-without-dll

Comment: @MikyDinescu That didn't work!  I can't find a way to do that without errors. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040583/compile-curllib-static-dll-completely-without-dll-dependency?lq=1

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here: 
Compile curllib_static.dll completely without dll dependency?" No, there are 0 answers there

Answer (score 1):

> Libraries like curl require you to have .dll files when running .exe
>   In theory you should be able to link those .dll statically to the .exe

No you can't. They are dynamic link libraries. DLLs can't be linked statically. If the supplier also supplies a static .lib file, you can link that *instead* of the DLL. It isn't the same thing.

> But I can't find a way to do that without errors and crashes.

Unsuprising, as there isn't one.

> But are there libraries which don't require external .dll files at runtime? That allow me to do a HTTP request?

Very likely, but why? What's your objection to DLLs?

Comment: Well, if you checked my other question, it does mention '.lib' files, but even when you include those '.lib' the '.exe' still asks for the '.dll' files

Comment: I want to build a portable app without DLLs

Comment: I am answering *this* question. If there is information missing from it that affects the range of correct answers, post it *here.* Don't expect people to chase you all over the site, or the Internet. They won't. There are static .libs, which is what I am talking about, and dynamic .libs, which is obviously what you still have, hence the need for the corresponding DLLs. You still haven't stated *why* you don't want DLLs; you've only reiterated that you don't. 'Portable app' doesn't add any information. No Windows application is portable off Windows anyway.

Comment: @user88888 you would like a single executable for distribution? You can make an self-extractor out of your code and dependencies (dlls, graphics, etc). See http://portableapps.com/.

Comment: @leesei Which self-extractor do you suggest?

Comment: If you like an installer interface (this may be and overkill for your use case), try [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). If you merely need a self extracting exe, follow [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Self-Extracting-excutables). And Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the `.lib` you are linking is not the `dll`'s implementation, it just contains some metainfo on the `dll`.

If you are trying to convert a `.dll` to a `.lib`, this may help (but it is daunting):

http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/

If everything fails, you should consider compiling static version of libcurl on you own

http://fluxxu.com/2010/12/08/building-static-libcurl-with-ssl-support-on-windows/  (note: export CURL_STATICLIB in your app)

[Building libcurl with SSL support on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197444/building-libcurl-with-ssl-support-on-windows)

Comment: Are you sure the '.lib' files inside libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc are incomplete?

Comment: I've not used Window's libcurl. Can you check the size of them?

Comment: @user88888 If using any specific .lib requires the corresponding .dll to be loaded, *obviously* it is 'incomplete'. You can tell by the size. Static .libs are very large, dynamic .libs are small.

Comment: I extracted the package and see a `curllib_static.lib` in `lib\Release\` which is 1.8Mb. Could you try that?

Comment: @user88888 I see, we thought you're linking the `libcurl_imp.lib`.

Comment: That conversion method requires you to write a regex to filter all the function calls... (there a thousands of them...) Isn't there an easier way???

Comment: Compiling from source? Reference added.

Comment: On compiling from source, MORE ERRORS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041439/vs2012-nmake-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: This is getting out of hand. You shouldn't have to change anything in your own source code, just link with a static .lib file. Which exactly are the DLLs that are being loaded when you do that?

Comment: @leesei: Try what? I already included curllib_static.lib AND those other .lib files ( libeay32.lib, libeay32.lib, libeay32.lib) in my VS2012 project

Comment: @EJP: After linking the .lib files ( libeay32.lib, libeay32.lib, libeay32.lib) and compiling the .exe, it still asks for libeay32.dll, openldap.dll, ssleay32.dll, etc at runtime

Comment: So *those* are the components that you need static .libs for, not Curl. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: I thought I downloaded those  .lib files ( libeay32.lib, libeay32.lib, libeay32.lib) here: http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl-devel-msvc

Comment: > When building an application that uses the static libcurl library, you must add 'CURL_STATICLIB' to preprocessor. Otherwise the linker will look for dynamic import symbols.  From the link I post, did you tried this one?

Comment: @leesei yes, I have done that as well... I tried to add 'HTTP_ONLY' as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: When building libcurl on Windows On VS2008, it could not find depencies like windows.h

Comment: Alas, then I'm out of ideas, sorry ><. Can you reconsider using the .dll as is?