# build openssl on win64 fail

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, msys, mingw-w64

when run this command with `msys` in `openssl` source code directory.

```
$ ./config
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-mingw
Configuring for mingw
Configuring for mingw
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-libunbound   [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default]
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-ssl2         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
IsMK1MF=0
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_MT -DDSO_WIN32 -DL_ENDIAN -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_M                                                                                                                                                                                               EAN -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -march=i486 -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPE                                                                                                                                                                                               NSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM                                                                                                                                                                                                -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPO                                                                                                                                                                                               OL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
EX_LIBS       =-lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32
CPUID_OBJ     =x86cpuid.o
BN_ASM        =bn-586.o co-586.o x86-mont.o x86-gf2m.o
EC_ASM        =
DES_ENC       =des-586.o crypt586.o
AES_ENC       =aes-586.o vpaes-x86.o aesni-x86.o
BF_ENC        =bf-586.o
CAST_ENC      =cast-586.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4-586.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5-586.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-586.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-586.o sha256-586.o sha512-586.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=rmd-586.o
CMLL_ENC      =cmll-x86.o
MODES_OBJ     =ghash-x86.o
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/c/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev                                                                                                                                                                                               1/mingw32/bin/ranlib.exe
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl.exe
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
DES_PTR used
DES_RISC1 used
DES_UNROLL used
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_INDEX mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefined
e_os2.h => include/openssl/e_os2.h
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `set -e; target=links; for dir in crypto ssl engines ap                                                                                                                                                                                               ps test tools; do if [ -d "$dir" ]; then (      cd $dir && echo "making $target                                                                                                                                                                                                in $dir..." && TOP= && unset TOP ${LIB+LIB} ${LIBS+LIBS} ${INCLUDE+INCLUDE} ${IN                                                                                                                                                                                               CLUDES+INCLUDES} ${DIR+DIR} ${DIRS+DIRS} ${SRC+SRC} ${LIBSRC+LIBSRC} ${LIBOBJ+LI                                                                                                                                                                                               BOBJ} ${ALL+ALL} ${EXHEADER+EXHEADER} ${HEADER+HEADER} ${GENERAL+GENERAL} ${CFLA                                                                                                                                                                                               GS+CFLAGS} ${ASFLAGS+ASFLAGS} ${AFLAGS+AFLAGS} ${LDCMD+LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS+LDFLAGS}                                                                                                                                                                                                ${SCRIPTS+SCRIPTS} ${SHAREDCMD+SHAREDCMD} ${SHAREDFLAGS+SHAREDFLAGS} ${SHARED_L                                                                                                                                                                                               IB+SHARED_LIB} ${LIBEXTRAS+LIBEXTRAS} ${APPS+APPS} && C:/Program Files (x86)/min                                                                                                                                                                                               gw-w64/i686-6.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/make -e LC_ALL=C PLATFORM='                                                                                                                                                                                               mingw' PROCESSOR='' CC='gcc' CFLAG='-DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_MT -DDSO_WIN32 -DL_ENDI                                                                                                                                                                                               AN -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -march=i486 -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN                                                                                                                                                                                               _ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m                                                                                                                                                                                                -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM                                                                                                                                                                                                -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM' AS='gcc' ASFLAG='-DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_M                                                                                                                                                                                               T -DDSO_WIN32 -DL_ENDIAN -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -march=i                                                                                                                                                                                               486 -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT                                                                                                                                                                                                -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -                                                                                                                                                                                               DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -c' AR='ar  r' NM=                                                                                                                                                                                               'nm' RANLIB='/c/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/                                                                                                                                                                                               mingw32/bin/ranlib.exe' RC='windres' CROSS_COMPILE='' PERL='C:/Program Files/Git                                                                                                                                                                                               /usr/bin/perl.exe' ENGDIRS='ccgost' SDIRS='objects md4 md5 sha mdc2 hmac ripemd                                                                                                                                                                                                whrlpool des aes rc2 rc4 idea bf cast camellia seed modes bn ec rsa dsa ecdsa dh                                                                                                                                                                                                ecdh dso engine buffer bio stack lhash rand err evp asn1 pem x509 x509v3 conf t                                                                                                                                                                                               xt_db pkcs7 pkcs12 comp ocsp ui krb5 cms pqueue ts srp cmac' LIBRPATH='/usr/loca                                                                                                                                                                                               l/ssl/lib' INSTALL_PREFIX='' INSTALLTOP='/usr/local/ssl' OPENSSLDIR='/usr/local/                                                                                                                                                                                               ssl' LIBDIR='lib' MAKEDEPEND='$${TOP}/util/domd $${TOP} -MD gcc' DEPFLAG='-DOPEN                                                                                                                                                                                               SSL_NO_DEPRECATED -DOPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 -DOPENSSL_NO_GMP -DOPENSSL_NO                                                                                                                                                                                               _JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_RF                                                                                                                                                                                               C3779 -DOPENSSL_NO_SCTP -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_ST                                                                                                                                                                                               ORE -DOPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST -DOPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS' MAKEDEPPROG='gcc' SHAR                                                                                                                                                                                               ED_LDFLAGS='' KRB5_INCLUDES='' LIBKRB5='' ZLIB_INCLUDE='' LIBZLIB='' EXE_EXT='.e                                                                                                                                                                                               xe' SHARED_LIBS='' SHLIB_EXT='.dll.a' SHLIB_TARGET='cygwin-shared' PEX_LIBS='' E                                                                                                                                                                                               X_LIBS='-lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32' CPUID_OBJ='x86cpuid.o' BN_ASM='bn-586.o co-5                                                                                                                                                                                               86.o x86-mont.o x86-gf2m.o' EC_ASM='' DES_ENC='des-586.o crypt586.o' AES_ENC='ae                                                                                                                                                                                               s-586.o vpaes-x86.o aesni-x86.o' CMLL_ENC='cmll-x86.o' BF_ENC='bf-586.o' CAST_EN                                                                                                                                                                                               C='cast-586.o' RC4_ENC='rc4-586.o' RC5_ENC='rc5-586.o' SHA1_ASM_OBJ='sha1-586.o                                                                                                                                                                                                sha256-586.o sha512-586.o' MD5_ASM_OBJ='md5-586.o' RMD160_ASM_OBJ='rmd-586.o' WP                                                                                                                                                                                               _ASM_OBJ='wp_block.o wp-mmx.o' MODES_ASM_OBJ='ghash-x86.o' ENGINES_ASM_OBJ='' PE                                                                                                                                                                                               RLASM_SCHEME='coff' FIPSLIBDIR='' FIPSDIR='/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0' FIPSCANLIB="                                                                                                                                                                                               ${FIPSCANLIB:-}" THIS=${THIS:-links} MAKEFILE=Makefile MAKEOVERRIDES= TOP=.. DIR                                                                                                                                                                                               =$dir $target ) || exit 1; fi; done'
Makefile:438: recipe for target 'links' failed
make: *** [links] Error 1
```

I'm using `win64` work station,and I tried the guide in `INSTALL.WIN64`

```
You will need Microsoft Platform SDK, available for download at
 http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/. As per
 April 2005 Platform SDK is equipped with Win64 compilers, as well
 as assemblers, but it might change in the future.
```

However I don't have Microsoft Platform SDK,and I don't know which file should I download since the link is now redirected .So I tried the guide in `INSTALL.WIN32` then I am stuck here.

**UPDATE:**
After I move the mingw to a no `(` path it fail in another place.

```
DES_INT used
RC4_CHUNK is unsigned long long
e_os2.h => include/openssl/e_os2.h
making links in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Downloads/openssl-1.0.2k/crypto'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'links'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Downloads/openssl-1.0.2k/crypto'
Makefile:438: recipe for target 'links' failed
make: *** [links] Error 1
```

the other part is most similar with upper block.

**UPDATE** :after use Microsoft VisualStudio build tool

After I use the windows native ms build tool.when I met

```
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak 
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041439/vs2012-nmake-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).Again I run the same command.It fails on another error.

```
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak 
ms\uplink.c(11) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x2'
```

In my situation this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874987/1278112) almost fix it.However I'm using a different version of the .net framework,then I found the detail version number with help of this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx).And now I stuck here.

```
d:\Downloads\openssl-1.0.2k>nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Building OpenSSL
        cl /Fotmp32dll\md4_dgst.obj  -Iinc32 -Itmp32dll /MD /Ox -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -Gs0 -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK -I. -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE /Zi /Fdtmp32dll/lib -D_WINDLL  -DOPENSSL_BUILD_SHLIBCRYPTO -c .\crypto\md4\md4_dgst.c
md4_dgst.c
.\crypto\md4\md4_dgst.c(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I find in a variable in the Makefile which makes me feel wired.But not sure it's the right place to change.

> OPENSSLDIR=/usr/local/ssl

Comment: This *might* come from `Program Files (x86)`. Parenthesis are special in a Bourne shell, because they start a new subprocess.

Comment: In a vacuum, you can use the [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). It avoids the massive download and the Visual Studio expiring trial. MinGW is an extra wrinkle... With the tools in place, why not perform the native Win32 or Win64 build on Windows?

Comment: I would like to try this just didn't find the right tool as I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build openssl on win64 it's easier to use their native [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).Use `VS native tools command` is recommended,found detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041439/vs2012-nmake-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).If the `vcvar32.bat` doesn't work,refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm/3874987#3874987) to modify it.The .Net version reference is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx).After all these I built `openssl-1.0.2k` on `Win64/x64` finally.

Answer (score 1):

In a Bourne shell (`/usr/bin/sh`), parentheses are used to create a subprocess, see e.g. [Bash - Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

> Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell environment to be created (see Command Execution Environment), and each of the commands in list to be executed in that subshell.

---

In the error message, there's a sub-Make called

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/make -e LC_ALL=C PLATFORM=...
```

containing parentheses. This might be fixed by quoting the command, e.g.

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/make" -e LC_ALL=C PLATFORM=...
```

This should prevent the shell from interpreting the parentheses as a command to create a subshell.

---

There may be other places containing some `(x86)` or `(...)`.

Comment: As you said `There may be other places containing some (x86) or (...).`  so I move the `mingw` to a valid path.It works thank you!

Comment: @Shihe yes, installing GCC in a path with spaces (and apparently parentheses) is not a good idea. Note that you might want to take a look at [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io), which contains a lot of binary packages prebuilt to your satisfaction, such as OpenSSL.

Comment: I installed `msys2` and run `./config` it asked for `perl 5`.and where can I find openssl lib by msys2?

Comment: @ShiheZhang Looking at the question, it already found Perl at `PERL=/usr/bin/perl.exe`. Openssl library usually is in some `lib` subdirectory, but you haven't built it yet.

Comment: `msys` found perl,however the `msys2` still complain `You need perl 5`.and in `C:\msys64\usr\lib\openssl\engines` there are only some `*.so` files.

Comment: .so files are shared libraries, that's like DLL on Windows. You may search for Perl in msys/msys2 with something like `find c:/msys* -iname '*perl*'`. This will take long because it searches the whole msys installation. You may also try Windows search; maybe the indexer has your Perl in its database.