# How do I solve the issue "No module name Botan"

Tags: python, cmd, pip, botan

I am using windows 8 and python 3.6.1 I've done the following command in my cmd:

pip install cryptoshop

However, when I run the following python code:

```
from cryptoshop import encryptfile
from cryptoshop import decryptfile

result1 = encryptfile(filename="test", passphrase="mypassphrase", algo="srp")
print(result1)

result2 = decryptfile(filename="test.cryptoshop", passphrase="mypassphrase")
print(result2)
```

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in 
    from cryptoshop import encryptfile
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptoshop__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from cryptoshop.cryptoshop import encryptfile
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptoshop\cryptoshop.py", line 56, in 
    from ._cascade_engine import encry_decry_cascade
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptoshop_cascade_engine.py", line 27, in 
    from ._nonce_engine import generate_nonce_timestamp
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptoshop_nonce_engine.py", line 39, in 
    import botan
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botan'

Now, I obviously know that you must install botan into python in order to use it. However, this is where I am running into an issue. I've downloaded Botan from this link as instructed:

https://github.com/randombit/botan

And then I've followed these instructions in an attempt to install Botan:

```
./configure.py [--prefix=/some/directory]
make
make install
```

However, when I type make into the command line I get an error saying there is no such command. And then when I go to run my above Python code I still get the no module Botan error. So obviously I am doing something run. How can I properly install Botan into my Python 3.6 directories so that I can use cryptoshop.

I've also attempted to do pip install Botan, as that is how I've installed so many other python libraries but that has been unsuccessful as well.

Answer (score 4):

`make` is a linux command

According to the `botan` website you can use `nmake` as a replacement on windows ( http://wiki.c2.com/?UsingNmake ) :

> **On Windows**
>
> You need to have a copy of Python installed, and have both Python and
>   your chosen compiler in your path. Open a command shell (or the SDK
>   shell), and run:

```
  $ python configure.py --cc=msvc (or --cc=gcc for MinGW) [--cpu=CPU] 
  $ nmake 
  $ botan-test.exe 
  $ nmake install
```

> Botan supports the nmake replacement Jom which enables you to run
>   multiple build jobs in parallel.

source : https://botan.randombit.net/manual/building.html

Comment: when i run these exact commands i still get nmake is not recognized. I ran the following at the location of my botan install. python configure.py --cc=msvc [--cpu=CPU] then ran nmake and got the error

Comment: You forgot to mention that `nmake` requires visual C++ to be installed to work in a windows machine. @tgrim90 make sure you Visual C++ installed in your windows machine

Comment: @deaspo is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: @tgrim90 you can just install the SDK, Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017, without having to install the whole Visual Studio. It contains all the needed components. Other option is to run the code in Ubuntu

Comment: @deaspo ok so i did that i downloaded this:  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017. And then installed it and tried to run the above code in the command line and still get nmake is not recognizable

Comment: Are you running the command in a command shell that was packaged with the SDK or just the general Windows Command prompt?

Comment: @deaspo I also get an error with [--cpu=CPU] am i doing something wrong there as well?

Comment: just windows command prompt i cannot find an shell packaged with the sdk or the install. where does visual c++ usually install?

Comment: In the start menu, after restarting the machine there should be `visual c++  20XX XX-bit command prompt`

Comment: Edit your post?

Comment: @deaspo so where would I find the shell packaged with the sdk on windows 8.

Comment: Search in start for Visual C++ ...... One of the options should be Visual C++ 20XX XX-bit Command Prompt. That is if you already installed it

Comment: @deaspo I have already installed it, it shows up in my programs and features on my control panel, however it does not show up when i search for it

Comment: Here is the correct link http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: @deaspo do i download for 2015 or 2017?

Comment: @tgrim90 sorry about the earlier link

Comment: Any would do, yoo just want to use the `nmake` tool which is built into both

Comment: @deaspo and what exactly should I be downloading, I assume the performance tools that include a standalone command prompt? but i'm not sure

Comment: @deaspo sorry, but it won't let me download just the tools it seems to make me download vs as well

Comment: @deaspo nevermind now after 25 tries it let me download it

Comment: @deaspo downloaded Performance Tools for Visual Studio, went through the install, restarted my machine, searched for visual c++ and still not showing up. is there a folder on my machine i could look for the command prompt on?

Comment: See the following: https://superuser.com/questions/146577/where-do-i-find-nmake-for-windows-7-x64 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041439/vs2012-nmake-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507646/nmake-exe-is-not-found-in-the-windows-system32-folder-how-to-setup-nmake-comman

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's how I made it work on a **Mac**

Assuming you have `brew` installed.

```
brew install botan
```

You may need to install other functionality first:

```
brew install gmp
brew install mpfr
brew install mpc
```

Find out where botan got installed with `brew info botan`.
My location is `/usr/local/Cellar/botan/2.6.0`

In that folder, you'll find `lib/python2.7/site-packages`, copy the contents of this folder into your Python's installation `site-packages` folder.

**Note 1:** At the time of this writing, only python 2.7 seems to be supported, but I'm using python 3.6 and everything seems to be working.

**Note 2:** If the file is called `botan2.py`, you may need to rename it to `botan.py` in your python's `site-packages` folder.